# Redirect to login page with some extra parameters in URL

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot with Spring Security, and I would like to redirect to the login with a custom parameter in the URL different then login?error or login?logout.

Currently when I do the redirect the login url get strip from parameters different to "error" or "logout" pageI have authentication through AD that any authorized user can login.

For example in my controller I have something like:

```
   return "redirect:/login?invalid-token";
```

And I would like to do in the login page something likehe view

```
   <div th:if="${param.invalid-token}" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Invalid token message.</div>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: It's not clear to me what your issue is. Is it that you want to allow any user access to the url /login?invalid-token?

Comment: I would like to have in the login page 2 forms one for submit credentials and the other one when a user forgets his password and he would like to reset it  So, the idea with this is to submit the reset form and get back to the login page with a message saying like "you will get the reset URL by email".  I know spring security redirects with a url parameter like error or logout,however how can I put a different parameter for this scenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm still not fully understanding your problem, but I am taking a pretty good guess.

Likely your problem is that you are redirecting to /login?invalid-token and Spring Security is not allowing anonymous access to that page. To fix it, use the following:

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        ...
```

Note that formLogin().permitAll() is very restrictive. It only allows access to the login page and the login error page that Spring Security knows about. The above makes it more permissive.

Comment: Thanks very much Rob, I had only formLogin().permitAll() when I include the code that you suggested is working now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set it as a part of your model, in your controller:

```
if(invalid-token != null){
    model.addattribute("invalid-token", invalid-token);
}

return "view";
```

And then you can do the JSTL like this:

```
<c:if test=${!empty invalid-token}>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">${!empty invalid-token}</div>
</c:if>
```

EDIT:

You don't actually have to do the check. You can just add the div like this:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">${invalid-token}</div>
```

It will only show if you have assigned the invalid-token on your model (depending on your styling)

Comment: Thanks Michael, this works but the page URL is incorrect, for example when I submit the form to this address /users/something; then I will come back to the login page by calling the view like you said, that works however the url has the same URL that I use to submit the form.

Comment: Alright. Then you need to use session, to set the error Message. Then you can use: return "redirect:/login"